# How to make implicit conversion work during pattern matching

Tags: scala, enums, implicit-conversion, scala-2.10

I have an enum for keywords and operators (and some other too), e.g. (all are similar):

```
object Keywords extends Enumeration {
    val AND, ARRAY, BEGIN, ...= Value

    case class Keyword(keyword: Value) extends Token[Value] {
        def this(keyword: String) = this(Keywords.fromString(keyword))
        def value = keyword
    }

    implicit def valueToKeyword(keyword: Value) = new Keyword(keyword)
}
```

this implicit conversion allows me to pass enum values where `Token`s are expected e.g.

```
def testFunction[T](t: Token[T]) = ...
testFunction(Keywords.ARRAY) // gets converted
testFunction(Operators.PLUS) // gets converted too
```

it also seems that the same implicit conversion is not applied during matching i.e.

```
val token = new Keyword("ARRAY")
token match {
    case Keywords.ARRAY => ... // not selected but SHOULD be
    case Operators.PLUS => ... // completely different Enum
    ...
}
```

**Why? How to overcome this?**

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because:

```
token match {
  case Keywords.ARRAY => println("Array")
  case _ => println("Something else")
}
```

is essentially a [PartialFunction](http://sandrasi-sw.blogspot.hu/2012/03/understanding-scalas-partially-applied.html) with the following type signature: `PartialFunction[Keywords.Value, Unit]`. Which means an implicit won't be applied, because it's either [isDefinedAt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) or it isn't for that input.

If it isn't defined than `case _ => ...` will catch everything in my example code. If it's not defined at all and nothing will match it then you will get a [MatchError](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.MatchError) thrown.

In your case `token` of type `Token[Value]` isn't defined in the Partial Function that the match will compile to, because only types of `Keywords.Value` are defined.

### Three solutions

If you really want implicits then you could explicitly ask for an implicit (yes, that sentence is funny :))

```
implicitly[Keywords.Value](token) match {
  case Keywords.ARRAY => println("Array")
  case _ => println("Something else")
}
```

Or you can explicitly state the type of `token`, to invoke the implicit magic:

```
val token: Keywords.Value = new Keyword("ARRAY")
token match {
  case Keywords.ARRAY => println("Array")
  case _ => println("Something else")
}
```

Or the simplest solution if you can live without implicits:

```
token.value match {
  case Keywords.ARRAY => println("Array")
  case _ => println("Something else")
}
```

I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but I hope that you understood what `match {...}` really means and what Partial Functions are.

Comment: Thanks. The solutions are somewhat helpful, but what about when I have to match really different things? i.e. token can be a `Token[Value]` (== `Keyword`) or a `Token[Int]` ( == `IntegerLiteral` ) ?

Comment: @AkosKrivachy What about defining a `match` method for the `Keyword` class that will do the implicit conversion to a `Keywords.Value`? I tried [something similar](http://pastebin.com/9CkszZGf) and I failed. I'm uncertain about how to pass a `case` block to such a method. The syntax for the `match` method should be the same as for a regular `match` and solve the problem.

Comment: @Trylks Well writing your own `match` does not really solve the problem, but creates different code. The implicit doesn't need to be invoked since you have access to the underlying `result` value. I fixed your code to work: http://pastebin.com/EBPx0sGC but you have to explicitly use `a \`match\` { ... }` when calling it so it's not a super-nice solution. Also try commenting out the implicit and my bit of example code will continue to work, so this is somewhat a different problem.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy I see. I thought the backticks would not be needed when invoking the method, only on definition, so yes, different code semantically AND syntactically :/ (You are right, the implicit is there for any regular use, but it doesn't work for `match` nor is needed for

     ` `match` `
). The good thing: now I know what is a `PartialFunction` :) Thanks a lot.